# classname is missing

Tags: java

I have my java file under org/myorg

```
  package org.myorg;
  import java.io.*;
  import java.util.*;
  import java.net.*;
  import org.apache.hadoop.fs.*;
  import org.apache.hadoop.conf.*;
  import org.apache.hadoop.io.*;
  import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.*;
  import org.apache.hadoop.util.*;

  public class Write{
    public static void main (String [] args) throws Exception{
            try{
                    Path pt=new Path("hdfs:localhost:8020/user/jfor/out/abc");
                    FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(new Configuration());
                    BufferedWriter br=new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fs.create(pt,true)));
                                               // TO append data to a file, use fs.append(Path f)
                    String line;
                    line="Disha Dishu Daasha";
                    System.out.println(line);
                    br.write(line);
                    br.close();
            }catch(Exception e){
                    System.out.println("File not found");
            }
    }
}
```

I compiled it using

```
 javac -classpath hadoop-0.20.1-dev-core.jar org/myorg/Write.java
```

from the parent directory of `org`.

Write.class is created under `org/myorg`

I run it using

java org.myorg.Write

from the parent directory of `org`

It says

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/fs/FSDataOutputStream
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
```

But i downloaded jar from [this link](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/h/Downloadhadoop0201corejar.htm). This link says FSDataOutputStream class is present.

What could be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have the classpath set for execution - you have it set during compile:

Windows:

```
java -cp .;hadoop-0.20.1-dev-core.jar org.myorg.Write
```

UNIX:

```
java -cp .:hadoop-0.20.1-dev-core.jar org.myorg.Write
```

You have to specify the classpath (-cp) to include the current directory, in your case, as well as the hadoop jar file.

Comment: I run it from the parent directory of `org` It says "File Not Found" Unix system

Answer (score 0):

You have to give the exact path where the `jar` is present

```
java -cp .:give_the_path_to_the_jar org.myorg.Write
```

for Example if it is present in my desktop

```
java -cp .:/home/neeraj/Desktop/hadoop-0.20.1-dev-core.jar org.myorg.Write
```

> `.`  represent the current directory

**Note :** These above example is for linux(ubuntu) , if you need to use in Windows than you have to use `;` instead of `:`

Comment: What if i am in Desktop? Do i need to give full path?

Comment: No then you don't have to give it , if both the `Java class file` and  the jar is present in the same location and you are calling the `java` command from there then there is no need to give full path